# Problema al juntar tablas SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta:

```
SELECT p.id, 
       resultado, 
       (count(resultado)*100)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IAssesment_Evaluaciones WHERE area='TlP/LOP2.1') count 
    FROM IAssesment_Evaluaciones e 
    INNER JOIN IAssesment_Resultados r 
       ON e.id=r.id_evaluacion 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados t 
       ON t.id=r.resultado 
    INNER JOIN IAssesment_Preguntas p 
       ON r.id_pregunta=p.id 
    WHERE area='TlP/LOP2.1' 
    GROUP BY resultado,p.id ORDER BY p.id,resultado
```

Ésta muestra bien los datos:

```
id  resultado   count
1   2           100
2   2           100
3   2           50
3   3           50
4   1           33
4   2           66
5   1           50
5   2           33
5   3           16
```

Mi problema es que la tabla de `IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados` tiene 3 tipos de resultados (1,2,3). Lo que necesito es que mi consulta me regrese los 3 tipos de valores aunque no tenga ningún valor. Como ejemplo de los resultados de la consulta anterior, este es el resultado que necesito:

```
id    resultado    COUNT
1    2             100
1    1             0
1    3             0
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: En base a lo que colocas como información que necesitas, la tabla IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados que información para cuando el id = 1 ?. Porque veo que cuando el Id=5 te trae los 3 tipos de resultados. Puede ser que no tienes información para los tipos resultados 1 y 3 con id = 1

Comment: Hola, utilizo la versión 2014, los datos que necesito siempre son los diferentes tipos de valor que hay en la tabla IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados, es correcto que no tengo la info de valores 1 y 3, eso es lo que quiero lograr, que me regrese los 3 tipos de valor, si no existe que sea 0

Answer (score 1):

La tabla `IAssesment_Tipo_Resultado` tiene otros tipos de resultados pero no los seleccionaron por qué no generan coincidencia en el JOIN

Usa una combinación de `ISNULL` Y `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT p.id, 
       ISNULL(resultado,t.Id) as resultado, 
       ISNULL((count(resultado)*100)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
       IAssesment_Evaluaciones WHERE area='TlP/LOP2.1'),0) AS COUNT
    FROM IAssesment_Evaluaciones e 
    INNER JOIN IAssesment_Resultados r 
       ON e.id=r.id_evaluacion 
    FULL OUTER JOIN IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados t 
       ON t.id=r.resultado 
    INNER JOIN IAssesment_Preguntas p 
       ON r.id_pregunta=p.id 
    WHERE area='TlP/LOP2.1' 
    GROUP BY ISNULL(resultado,t.Id),p.id ORDER BY p.id,ISNULL(resultado,t.Id)
```

Comment: Hola @Caledron_C, no me sirve esto

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de la información de cada tabla??

Comment: Claro, tengo 3 tablas IAssesment_Evaluaciones, IAssesment_Resultados, IAssesment_Tipo_Resultados, estas son las importantes, la tabla de evaluaciones tiene un id, fecha, usuario   la segunda tabla tiene id id_pregunta resultado id_evaluacion

Comment: Este es un post el cual me ayuda de referencia  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a002425-92f3-4d67-ab43-64786e152f04/mostrar-todos-los-datos-de-varias-tablas?forum=sqlserveres